# Python script connecting to Redshift using OKTA authentication - psycopg2 jdbc url

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to open a python connection to Redshift from Sagemaker Jupiter notebook. It works fine with psycopg2 method when I pass user name and password, however I now want to connect using OKTA Authentication and for that purpose I shouldn't pass in username and password but I'd like to pass in a jdbc URL with all connection string parameters like DBGroups, Login_url etc that will allow me to authenticate via OKTA. that I already have correct. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75667321/220997

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

# import pandas for testing
import pandas as pd

# define URL params and connection params
url_params = {
    'drivername': 'redshift+redshift_connector',
    'database': 'mydb',
    'host': 'mycompany.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    'port': '5439'
}

conn_params = {
    'iam': True,
    'credentials_provider': "BrowserSamlCredentialsProvider",
    'idp_host': 'mycompany.okta.com',
    'cluster_identifier': "abc",
    'region': 'us-east-1',
    'ssl_insecure': False,
    'login_url': 'https://mycompany.okta.com/home/abcsdf'
}

# construct sqlalchemy engine
engine = sa.create_engine(
    url=URL.create(**url_params),
    connect_args=conn_params
)

# test connection
conn = engine.connect()
conn.close()
```