# Connecting Python SQLAlchemy to Redshift Connector with SAML Okta

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

Looking for a way to write some python code to connect to Redshift using my okta MFA credentials. I'm able to connect using login/pw but need to use Okta SAML 2FA. Using sqlalchemy, so I can load into a Pandas dataframe and do some analysis.

There's a redshift connector driver I'm trying to use.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/python-connect-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of a coworker, I was able to get it working. The key section is the connection parameters, specifically: credentials_provider, login_url, idp_host.

Some helpful links:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/federated-api-access-to-amazon-redshift-using-an-amazon-redshift-connector-for-python/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/python-connect-examples.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/options-for-providing-iam-credentials.html

See below code:

```
# install required packages
# pip install sqlalchemy
# pip install redshift-connector
# pip install sqlalchemy-redshift

# import required packages
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

# import pandas for testing
import pandas as pd

# define URL params and connection params
url_params = {
    'drivername': 'redshift+redshift_connector',
    'database': 'mydb',
    'host': 'mycompany.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    'port': '5439'
}

conn_params = {
    'iam': True,
    'credentials_provider': "BrowserSamlCredentialsProvider",
    'idp_host': 'mycompany.okta.com',
    'cluster_identifier': "abc",
    'region': 'us-east-1',
    'ssl_insecure': False,
    'login_url': 'https://mycompany.okta.com/home/abcsdf'
}

# construct sqlalchemy engine
engine = sa.create_engine(
    url=URL.create(**url_params),
    connect_args=conn_params
)

# test connection
conn = engine.connect()
conn.close()


# sample usage
# SQLAlchemy can only prepare one statement at a time - queries
# with multiple statements must be executed separately.
test_id = 178
drop_test_table = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test;"""
populate_test_table = f"""
SELECT * into #test from foo;
"""
select_from_test_table = """SELECT * FROM #test;"""

# execute statements
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(drop_test_table)
conn.execute(populate_test_table)
df = pd.read_sql_query(
    sql=select_from_test_table,
    con=conn,
    index_col=None
)
conn.execute(drop_test_table)
conn.close()
engine.dispose()

print(df)
```